# .net oracle insert query

Tags: .net, oracle

I have to pass a sql query to oracle database.

```
insert into items values('5', 'table', '77', '5-Jan-2017')
```

now the first column is a integer and last is a date. Right now I don't have access to database. Will this query run from .net code will be able to insert code properly. Please advice.

Comment: Yes, it will work, but if you pass some other value in a date like '5-6-2017' that might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

passing numbers should not be in single quotes ''.Moreover you should have smth like jdbc code in your .net to add it to your table like this:

```
public static string m_ConnectionString =
    @"Network Library=dbmssocn; Data Source=*server ip*,*port*; database=*db name*; " +
    @"User id=*db username*; Password=*db pass*;";
public static SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(m_ConnectionString);
```

if you donot have access it will work though.